# How to send an XML file to API by javascript

Tags: javascript, api, rest, post

I am reporting to you today with a polite notification of me being directed, which I am kindly doing when trying to send an API request. Yes, I know, there is a right to provide information about JS / AJAX / JQuery on the net, although it usually concerns reading API, so it is available for one API function. Below is the code:

Of course, I changed the API key on purpose, so that's not a problem, the key itself is fine. ;)

```js
<script>
UserAction () {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest ();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           // Common Action To Take When Document is ready:
            var answer = xhr.responseText;
            console.log ("ok" + response);
        }
    };
    xhr.open ('POST', 'https: //api5.esv2.com/v2/Api/Subscribers/', true);

    xhr.send ("POST https://api5.esv2.com/v2/Api/Subscribers/ HTTP / 1.1 Content-Type: text / xml <ApiRequest xmlns: xsi = \" http://www.w3.org/ 2001 / XMLSchema-instance \ "xmlns: xs = \" http: //www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema \ "> <ApiKey> KEY </ApiKey> <xsi data: type = \" Subscriber \ "> < Mode> AddAndUpdate </Mode> <Force> true </Force> <ListId> 1 </ListId> <Email> jan.kowalski@domena.com </Email> <Firstname> Jan </Firstname> <Lastname> Kowalski < /Lastname><TrackingCode>123</TrackingCode><Vendor>xyz</Vendor><Ip>11.22.33.44</Ip><Properties><Property><Id>5</Id><Value xsi: type = \ "xs: string \"> student </Value> </Property> <Property> <Id> 3 </Id> <Value xsi: type = \ "xs: dateTime \"> 1985-03-12 </Value> </Property></Properties></Data> </ApiRequest> ");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set headers properly and use your XML only in `send`.

```
xhr.open ('POST', 'https://api5.esv2.com/v2/Api/Subscribers/', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
xhr.send(XMLbody);
```

Depends on the situation (what kind of a response you are expecting) you may need to change this part too.

```
var answer = xhr.responseXML;
```

Comment: Just adding the first part of the code, unfortunately, did not help. Could you please explain to me exactly how to replace this part?
var answer = xhr.responseXML;

Comment: Are you passing only XML to your xhr.send ?  Without the POST, Content-Type and other junk included?